# Dynamically constructing a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been staring at this piece of code for nearly an hour and a half. In my inexperience I've no idea where I'm going wrong.

```
$gameInfo = array(
for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $friendsInfo[$i] = $facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]);
    array($randomfriends[$i],
          $friendsInfo[$i][first_name],
          $friendsInfo[$i][last_name],
          $friendsInfo[$i][hometown][name],
          $friendsInfo[$i][location][name],
          $friendsInfo[$i][about]
    );
    }
);
```

This is my attempt. As you can see the values are being pulled in from facebook. This is not the problem as each value appears if I echo. I want to take the values and put them into a multidimensional array that follows this structure.

```
$gameInfo =  array(
    array('first_name','last_name','hometown','location','about'),
    array('first_name','last_name','hometown','location','about'),
    array('first_name','last_name','hometown','location','about'),
    array('first_name','last_name','hometown','location','about'),
    array('first_name','last_name','hometown','location','about')
);
```

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what `$facebook->api()` gives you, but you probably want:

```
$gameInfo = array();

for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $gameInfo[] = $facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]);
}
```

or

```
$gameInfo = array();

for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $friend = $facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]);
    $gameInfo[] = array(
         $friend['first_name'],
         $friend['last_name'],
         $friend['hometown']['name'],
         $friend['location']['name'],
         $friend['about']
    );
}
```

**Update:**  If `api()` returns a JSON string, then you have to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$friend = json_decode($facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]), true);
```

---

No offense, but your whole code is wrong syntax. You might want to read about [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: Hi Felix I'm not sure how this work. I don't think I've explained myself very clearly. $facebook-> returns a json, $randomfriends is an array with the id of each friend I want to return further info about

Comment: @willmcneilly: If it returns a JSON string, then you have to use `json_decode()`.

Comment: Thank you works perfectly. I totally confused myself with this. No offense taken, I've a lot to learn

Answer (score 1):

```
$gameInfo = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $friendsInfo[$i] = $facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]);
    $gameInfo[] = array(
      $friendsInfo[$i][first_name],
      $friendsInfo[$i][last_name],
      $friendsInfo[$i][hometown][name],
      $friendsInfo[$i][location][name],
      $friendsInfo[$i][about]
    );
}
```

Out of curiosity was that code supposed to be like a python list comprehension? or was it from another language?

Comment: No sorry it's just me getting the syntax wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$gameInfo = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $friendsInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $randomfriends[$i]);
    $gameInfo[] = array(
      $friendsInfo['first_name'],
      $friendsInfo['last_name'],
      $friendsInfo['hometown']['name'],
      $friendsInfo['location']['name'],
      $friendsInfo['about']
    );
}
```